# Ajax success nor error not being called

Tags: java, jquery, ajax, spring

Noob of jquery/ajax is here, so be patient with me please! :)
I've been looking through net, but none of answers hit my needs so here is my problem:

I try to write a code and now I need to have a jquery function:

- After button click, jquery function calls specified controller method,
- Controller method gets array of objects from database,
- Controller method sends array of objects as json to jsp,
- Array of objects is handled by the same jquery function and do something (for example append content of some div) on my jsp.

And now here is my code:

build.gradle dependencies:

```
dependencies {
    compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa')
    compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web')
    compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-tomcat')
    compile('org.apache.tomcat.embed:tomcat-embed-jasper')
    compile('javax.servlet:jstl')
    compile group: 'javax.servlet', name: 'jstl', version: '1.2'
    compile group: 'postgresql', name: 'postgresql', version: '9.0-801.jdbc4'
    compile group: 'org.webjars', name: 'jquery', version: '2.2.4'
    compile group: 'com.googlecode.json-simple', name: 'json-simple', version: '1.1'
    compile group: 'org.webjars', name: 'jquery', version: '2.2.4'
    compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-devtools")
    compile group: 'org.json', name: 'json', version: '20090211'
    compile group: 'com.google.code.gson', name: 'gson', version: '2.3.1'
    compile 'javax.validation:validation-api:1.1.0.Final'
    compile 'org.hibernate:hibernate-validator:5.0.1.Final'

    runtime('com.h2database:h2')
    testCompile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test')
    testCompile group: 'com.h2database', name: 'h2', version: '1.3.148'
}
```

My jquery script:

```
<script>

        $(document).ready(function() {
            $("#testButton4").click(function(event){
                $.ajax({
                    type : 'GET',
                    url : '${pageContext.request.contextPath}/fetchComments',
                    success : function(response) {
                        $('#result').html(response.get(1).author);
                    },
                    error: function() {
                        alert("God dammit...");
                    }
                });
            });
        });
    </script>

...
<button id="testButton4"> Button4</button>

<div id="result"> Here content should be changed by button click. </div>
...
```

and my controller's code:

```
@RequestMapping(value="/fetchComments", method=RequestMethod.GET,produces="application/json")
    @ResponseBody
    public List<Comment> fetchComments() {

        System.out.println("");
        System.out.println("Fetching comments from database");

        List<Comment> commentList = (List<Comment>) commentRepository.findAllByOrderByIdAsc();
        for(Comment comment : commentList){
            System.out.println(comment.getId() + ", " + comment.getContent() + ", " + comment.getAuthor()+", "+comment.getPostId());
        }

        return commentList;

    }
```

For now none of my jquery functions (success/error) are working (I can see json data in dev tools but nothing is happening from jquery perspective). What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Try to print the success response in an alert, also check the response of your call in the console using F12.

Answer (score 0):

The  [Response](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Response/Response) object doesnt have `get` method, The data you are looking for would probably be within the body of the `Response` object.

Answer (score 0):

According to hint, that Mitul Maheshwari gave me, I displayed what came from controller. I have got objects. So all I had to do was simply `var list = JSON.stringify(response);`and now I can do all I want with json data calling `list` variable. Thanks!